# Route subdomain-rich requests to area view in MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using the [Maarten Balliauw approach](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx) to subdomain routing in MVC 3 application.

Basically I have the following two routes added to my RouteTable.Routes:

```
 _routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
                        "{user}.localhost",                                             
                        "{action}/{id}",                                                
                        new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "Index", user = "" });  

 _routes.MapRoute("Default",                                                                  
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                                               
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

The problem is that my `FileUpload` controller should reside in the separate MVC `Area` (called Upload).

I also need a {user} parameter to be getting passed into an Index action of the FileUpload controller. How should I set up this subdomain-to-area action redirect?

P.S. I can assure you that there seems to be no duplicates of this question on SO. Other's are asking how to treat a subdomain as an area, not how to treat subdomain as a parameter and then route request to a controller within an area.

Important Notice: I need the subdomain-to-area view route to be engaged whenever user navigates to subdomain only (like max.localhost.com), not when navigating to max.localhost.com/upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should as simples as this:

```
_routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
                        "{user}.localhost",                                             
                        "upload",                                                
                        new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "Index", user = "" });

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, string user) 
{

}
```

When you post to http://maxim.localhost/upload, the user variable will be set to 'maxim'.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I can't afford user navigating to `subdomain.domain/upload`. `/upload` adds a level of complexity to a request URL. You are probably correct, but cat I do something to have the same effect by client navigating to maxim.localhost and arriving at "upload" automatically?

Comment: By the way, for some reason even `max.localhost/upload/` doesn't work.

Comment: Tested even more. As a result, even if I configure it as you propose, a routing engine still looks for Views in `~/Views/FileUpload/Index.cshtml`, but should in `/Areas/Upload/Views/FileUpload/Index.cshtml`.

Comment: Proceeding with it. For some reason the controller is getting initialized correctly, but the area name is no specified in the `RouteData.DataTokens`. If I add it manually, it finds an Area view fine, but this is a nasty workaround.

Comment: I think the problem is in the DomainRoute class. Take a look at the solution I've blogged about: http://geekstuff.cc/2011/12/02/subdomain-routing-on-asp-net-mvc/ There is a line that adds the area to the DataTokens.